# Replacing nested for loop with numpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a script that takes a long time to process data and therefore I want to optimize it by replacing as many Python loops as possible with Numpy operations.

Current solution (not efficient):

```
def coordinate(prefix):
    for n in range(19000, 21000):
        for e in range(43000, 46400):
            encryptedString = encrypt_string(prefix + " N59 " + "{:.3f}".format(n/1000) + " E024 " + "{:.3f}".format(e/1000))
            return encryptedString
```

I want to replace the Python nested for loop with Numpy functions for maximum performance.

So far I managed to get 2 `NumPy` arrays already formated to 3 floating points.
Optimized solution:

```
def coordinate_opt(prefix):
    float_formatter = "{:.3f}".format
    np.set_printoptions(formatter={'float_kind':float_formatter})
    
    n = np.arange(19.000,21.000,0.001)
    e = np.arange(43.000,46.400,0.001)
    #TODO: Create a matrix out of n and e that matches every "n" with every "e" in order.
    #TODO: Iterate through the matrix (nditer?) and pass the floating numbers to encrypt function.
    return encryptedString
```

Question1: I'm struggling to figure out how to create a matrix out of those 2 arrays fulfilling the same purpose as the nested for loop (match every `n` to every `e` in order). What would be the most efficient way to do it?

Question2: In order to pass the floating numbers in the array/matrix to the "encrypt_string" function, I need to still iterate through the arrays/matrix. How could I achieve that in the most efficient way? (nditer?)

Comment: "Iterate through the matrix (nditer?)" might as well just use your loops then, `nditer` will be *slower*.

Comment: As long as the action is a pure Python function or expression that does not accept arrays, there isn't much you can do.  You still have to call it once for each array element.  In most cases it's that calling that takes the most time, not the iteration/accumulation mechanism itself.   Also numpy does not do anything special with strings - your encrypt and format are all Python string actions.

Comment: Also, if you are trying to do string operations, I doubt numpy will help.

Comment: The loops may not be your bottleneck, but the string formatting and concatenation are likely to be. I don't know of a way to speed that up in NumPy. You might have to code that in C directly if you want to speed it up. Or find a completely different way, e.g. using ASCII values or unicode codepoints directly (so it's all numbers, not characters. Which would seem to fit for something "encrypted").

Comment: Could you add a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to your post? For example, the function `encrypt_string` gets called, but what does it do?

Comment: Also, do you want to `return encryptedString`? Because this terminates the function `coordinate` in the first iteration (when `n=19000` and `e=43000`).